# NPM update all to latest version

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to update all my packages to the latest version:

```
npm outdated
```

Result:

```
Package                Current        Wanted        Latest  Location
cordova            3.4.0-0.1.0  3.6.3-0.2.13  3.6.3-0.2.13  cordova
commander                2.0.0         2.0.0         2.3.0  npm-check-updates > commander
async                   0.2.10        0.2.10         0.9.0  npm-check-updates > async
semver                   2.2.1         2.2.1         4.0.3  npm-check-updates > semver
read-package-json        1.1.9         1.1.9         1.2.7  npm-check-updates > read-package-json
npm                     1.3.26        1.3.26         2.1.2  npm-check-updates > npm
```

How can I do that?

I tried it:

```
sudo npm update -g cordova
```

And this too with no errors:

```
npm install npm-check-updates
```

But it's not working.

Thanks!!

Comment: Npm can't do that, try https://www.npmjs.org/package/npm-check-updates

Comment: @jgillich is there a bower equivalent ?

Comment: @Cétia I don't use bower so no idea, sorry.

Comment: @chemitaxis npm-check-updates has a readme that shows you how to use it. Installing it surely does nothing, you need to run it.

Comment: @chemitaxis did my answer help you in the end?

Answer (score 8):

npm can! For example, we will update cordova to the latest version:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova@latest
```

To update npm, just do the same:

```
sudo npm install -g npm@latest
```

EDIT:
Update all packages to latest with this:

```
npx npm-check-updates -u
npm install
```

Comment: Is there a way to update all packages to the latest, not just select ones?

Comment: Don't install random packages from npm using `sudo`.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how they are listed in your `package.json` you should edit the versions on each dependancy.

an example would be:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "grunt": "*"
}
```

Setting the version to `*` sets it to the latest version. Read about versioning dependancies here http://browsenpm.org/package.json

Once you have done that you can then tell NPM to install all the projects dependents.

`$ npm install`

---

**Tip**: if you are not automatically saving your projects dependants to your package.json, you should. Just add `--save` to the end of your install query. Like so

`$ npm install grunt --save`

Answer (score 2):

see this article 
[HOW TO: Update all npm packages in your project at once](https://medium.com/@_jh3y/how-to-update-all-npm-packages-in-your-project-at-once-17a8981860ea)

```
“scripts”: {   “update:packages”: “node wipe-dependencies.js &&
                  rm -rf node_modules && npm update --save-dev
                  && npm update --save” },
```

To run this on the command line:

```
npm run update:packages
```

OR only update packages in the npm registry:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const wipeDependencies = () => {
  const file  = fs.readFileSync('package.json')
  const content = JSON.parse(file)
  for (var devDep in content.devDependencies) {
    if (!content.devDependencies[devDep].includes(git)) {
      content.devDependencies[devDep] = '*'
    }
  }
  for (var dep in content.dependencies) {
    if (!content.dependencies[dep].includes(git)) {
      content.dependencies[dep] = '*'
    }
  }
  fs.writeFileSync('package.json', JSON.stringify(content))
}

if (require.main === module) {
  wipeDependencies()
} else {
  module.exports = wipeDependencies
}
```

Comment: you show a very unpleasant behaviour, why?